# Getting ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am using karma to run my meanjs project. I installed istanbul to check the test coverage of my project. But I am getting ReferenceError: describe is not defined.
What could be the issue??

Please help me.

Comment: can you please provide more information? Please share code snippet

Comment: Have fixed the issue by installing karma-coverage --save-dev instead of instanbul and importing required js files....